# Radiowave diffraction

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, diffraction, radio-frequency

When a far field propagated radio wave encounters an obstacle such as a mountain does the radio wave actually bend around the mountain? In other words should my receiving antenna on the other side of the mountain be pointed up towards the mountain peak or simply oriented towards the horizontal as if the mountain never existed. Which option will provide higher signal strength? Does Horizonral vs vertical polarisation have any effect? Does my proximity to the mountain shadow have any effect?